# Comparing values of each row with previous value for unique date

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have to create a separate where it shows the comparison of arr_delay of a row with previous row. If the arr_delay compared to previous row is high, it is 1 for and 0 if it is less.

[image: Data Sample]

[image: Output Sample]

The data is in descending order. Last flight is at the top and first flight is at the bottom.

I can compare first flight and last flight but not of each row for unique date and creating a table like this.

Comment: What if your previous row and current row has same value of arr_delay?

Comment: Then also 0. I am trying to find increment rows where there is increment in arr_delay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [df.shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) and [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
dataset['new_col'] = np.where(dataset['arr_delay'].shift(-1) < dataset['arr_delay'], 1, 0)
```

**Edit**

```
dataset['new_col'] = 0
for unique in dataset.Data.unique():
    new_df = dataset[dataset.Date == unique].copy()
    new_df['new_col'] = np.where(new_df['arr_delay'].shift(-1) < new_df['arr_delay'], 1, 0)
    dataset.loc[dataset.Date == unique] = new_df
```

**Edit 2** For the expected format try [df.pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html)

```
dataset.pivot(index = 'Date', columns = 'Aircraft', values ='new_col)
```

Comment: It works but it is also subtracting from arr_delay of different dates. I want for unique dates.

Comment: oh okay. I understand now. Give me few minutes.

Comment: @PrateekSingh Can you check if the edited answer works for you?

Comment: It works, but how can I arrange it in the format like I have shown. ( The example of excel file )

Comment: Can you add code so that I can reproduce your dataframe?

Comment: And how do I get flight_1 flight_2 values? Are these your aircraft values?

Comment: Consider for 02-01-2019, now the first flight would be Goa to Bengaluru. Second Flight would be Bengaluru to Hyderabad. The column name could be anything. I just want it in that format

Comment: @PrateekSingh Check the changes

Comment: I tired. It says " ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape"

Comment: Yeah that format is not possible with your data unless done manually. I don't understand it.

Comment: @There shouldn't be any duplicated values in Aircraft for same date. Then it will work.